# Convert IIF to CASE (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This is the second question I ask regarding a conversion from `IIF` to `CASE`.

The thing that confuses me from the `IIF` is when one of the conditions becomes a second `IIF`. When that happens in the `IIF` code, I have trouble understanding whether I need just to put it as another `WHEN`, or if I need to start an nested `CASE`.

This is the `IIF` statement that needs conversion.

```
IIF(([FirstPublicationDate] IS NULL), IIF(([PublicationDate] IS NULL), GETDATE(), [PublicationDate]), [FirstPublicationDate])
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try _executing_ it in your head as if you were the computer and you should understand the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a tree diagram:

```
                                                --- GETDATE() 
                                        (null) /
                                              /
                        --- PublicationDate - 
                (null) /                      \
                      /                        \
FirstPublicationDate -                          --- PublicationDate
                      \
                       \
                        --- FirstPublicationDate
```

It's clear that the `IIF` statements wants to return `FirstPublicationDate` if it's not null; then `PublicationDate` and finally `GETDATE()`. You can shorten it to a single, much more readable `COALESCE` statement:

```
SELECT COALESCE(FirstPublicationDate, PublicationDate, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

The same IIF can be written with nested CASE statement as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [FirstPublicationDate] IS NULL THEN
         CASE WHEN [PublicationDate] IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE [PublicationDate] END
       ELSE [FirstPublicationDate] END
```

Comment: OP asked for an explanaion about HOW it work. Not just to convert his code

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. A nested CASE makes sense. Also, side note, in the example, I think a closing END is missing. Thank you.

Comment: yes, case can be nested, but once you understud you will see no need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the not-nested equivalent of your IIFs, which is more redable

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN FirstPublicationDate IS NOT NULL THEN FirstPublicationDate
  WHEN PublicationDate      IS NOT NULL THEN PublicationDate 
  ELSE GETDATE() 
END
```

But even on most sqls you have for this case a powerful and simplest option:

```
SELECT COALESCE(FirstPublicationDate, PublicationDate, GETDATE())
```

You can read about [coalesce here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), includes a comparison to `case`